# Lab computers: high end now or average system and repurchase in a couple of years?

Tags: facilities-services

I have been asked to recommend systems for upcoming computer labs. I see 2 options.

1. Buy high end systems now. They will be expensive but will last longer.
2. Buy average systems now and buy again in a couple of years when these become obsolete.

Option 1 makes more sense to me with the bonus that the lab systems will actually qualify as high-end for some time. Option 2 may seem cheaper now but current systems will become dinosaurs in a couple of years and new systems will have to be bought. The total cost of both options may actually come out to be the same in the long run. However, Option 2 involves scrapping systems in a couple of years which I see as needless waste.

Can anyone here comment on this?

NOTE: I understand this may not be the right forum for this question. If so, I will be happy to be pointed to one that is.

Comment: What will the computers be used for? high end activity? or just basic office software/internet/email/etc.

Comment: High end use - Matlab, Mathematica, graphics editing and rendering, network simulations. To give an example of Option 1 recommendations, I would suggest 32GB memory even though the applications I mentioned run fine in 8GB. The idea is that when applications needing 32GB come around, these machines are still capable.

Comment: It depends so very much on use case.
 undergrade labs where it needs to have like 100 PC all running locally, would be totally different from research use where a whole lab might be servers from weak machines that use SSH (or remote desktop) to connects to a small number of very powerful machines.

I feel to the extent that you have been asked to recommend systems, but feel you can not. The responsible thing to do might be to admitt it and find someone else in your area who can, because the local knowledge we don't have is essencial. But this is such a interesting question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it should be migrated to ServerFault.SE

Comment: How is this lab funded? Is this a one-time funding pot, or will there be money around for the "repurchase later" strategy?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would argue in favor of getting the best available system that fits within your budget at the time of the purchase. You might be able to save some money now by buying a less powerful system, but the danger of doing so is that you can't necessarily guarantee that in *N* years, when you plan to buy the replacements, that you'll have the money in the budget to do so. Long-term funding guarantees really aren't, and what is promised today might not hold up several years from now.

By getting the best available system now, you postpone the "must replace" date a while, which can give you more time to find a replacement (or the funds to replace it, as need be). Also, if your money is time-restricted in its use (you have to use it this year, for instance), there's no real incentive to skimp.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on what hardware is needed. Look at the products that change significantly overtime, products that change most would be consumer and workstation models. Particularly latest solid state drives for more powerful workstations. Video cards last a while and will be used by your engineers. DDR4 is too new to worry about at this stage. You can go for it and future proof, but DDR3 will hold a stance for almost the next decade I would say, then it will be obsolete. Servers change less often, but they are no longer using traditional SCSI either XD.

**Workstations:** Go with latest generation Intel core processors, they are a tighter product line than all of AMDs, I would say, for most consumers. Go with solid state, that's new. Regular hard drives are getting old. But do consider SSD brand, as that will determine the lifetime.

**Servers:** Honestly, you shouldn't need to future proof or go with those HP mini servers where there's like 4 per 2U, bare with me I forgot the name. Server architecture doesn't change often due to long term support and reliability. Go with whatever is most cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

Unless all infrastructure is really very well unified and maintained, moving to the new workstation costs significant time so also money. Taking migration costs into consideration, changing hardware on a yearly basis may not be the best option. If ten researchers spend four days each getting own workstation into working shape again, it is forty person-days!

Migration costs can be reduced by making machines very network-bound, with nothing important stored locally. However this approach seems challenging, for some reasons near always being too slow and near always having not enough space on the server. I have seen many attempts to implement it and have never seen a true success.